# 2011 Toyota Tundra Back up Camera/Lamp Switch Problems

Tags: troubleshooting, camera, tundra

I have a 2011 Tundra with a OEM style back up camera (running through existing wiring). If the reverse lights will not come on (due to faulty back up lamp switch) will the camera not come on as well? Thanks!

Comment: Most of the time this is true. But some do not depend on lamps lighting up to get reverse camera signal.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you are having a problem it would be best to edit and make it clear what the issue is, the history of it and what you've tried to do to fix it.